# Creating a universal code

Tags: matlab, octave

I have been working on creating a universal equation to calculate the theta function. The current equation I have is not universal. This works for maximum of 2 thetas. If I have to do the calculation for theta more than 2, I have to manually modify the numbers within the brackets of `theta()`.

Is there any way to setup a universal function? something like `thata(j) = equation`. I have pasted two codes below, one that is working but not universal and the other that I tried playing with and still ended up with error.

Code 1:

```
for iter = 1:num_iters


    theta(1) = theta(1) - (alpha/m)*((X*theta-y)')*X(:,1),
    theta(2) = theta(2) - (alpha/m)*((X*theta-y)')*X(:,2);
    theta_hist(iter,1) = theta(1);
    theta_hist(iter,2) = theta(2);

end
```

Code 2:

```
num_cols = size(X,2)
for inter = 1:num_iters
    for j = 1:num_cols
        theta(j) = theta(j) - (alpha/m)*((X*theta-y)')*X(:,j),
    end,
end,
```

The challenge with this code is that the when the code goes through the loop second time (`i`=1, `j`=2). The function is using the new value of the theta. This is screwing up the calculation.

Any feedbacks or suggestion is greatly appreciated.

More description of this issue is mentioned in the link below:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1XwAVV1OBN9BhQ7n60F2oEUoT263t_2hcAAuCaroR-2g/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: This is not R code. Please add the correct language tag.

Comment: Sorry, I was working on R and Octave. Then got confused. Thanks for fixing.

Comment: What are the dimensions of all the input variables (in the general case)?

Comment: X,y, theta are the input variables. X and y are taken from the csv file. theta is calculated through this equation. alpha is a constant dictated by the user and the m is the length of the matrix X or y.

Comment: You still did not provide the **dimensions** for the variables (and better yet a reproducible example)

Answer (score 1):

After multiple iterations, I was able to answer my own question.

The code is posted on github in the link below:
https://github.com/Boniface316/Octave/tree/master/GradientDescent_ThetaCalculator

Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

You should vectorize your code. You haven't provided matrix dimenstions and/or sample inputs, but if I'm guessing it correctly, the following should give you what you need:

```
% Some random inputs
alpha = 1;
m = 1;
num_iters = 15;
N = 5; k = 12;
X = randn(k,N);
y = randn(k,1);

theta = zeros(N,1);
theta_hist = zeros(N,num_iters);
for i = 1:num_iters
    theta = theta - (alpha/m)*X'*(X*theta-y);
    theta_hist(:,i) = theta;
end
```

Comment: I tried similar thing. Here is the challenge I have.

Comment: Sorry, what? What challenge?

Comment: I am typing the challenge as we speak. Sorry the above was a mistake.

Comment: Since the comment was too long, I have posted the comment on the following link:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1XwAVV1OBN9BhQ7n60F2oEUoT263t_2hcAAuCaroR-2g/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: It is actually vice versa. Your original code has the first element of `theta` modified by the time the second element gets updated. The vectorized version I provided, on the other hand, uses the whole `theta` vector from the previous iteration, which I believe is what you're after.

Comment: Also, better update your question than post the comment elsewhere.